# Using lapply to run exact binomial test over rows of a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to run a exact test to compare the observed vs. expected over many different pairs of observations and expectations.

For each row, I want to compare `data$readCount` to `data$refFraction` to the constant number of `trials` (which is the sum of all of the `data$readCounts`).

The way I was considering doing this is

```
test <- function(x, p, n){binom.test(x, n, p, alternative="two-sided")}
result <- lapply(data[c("readCount", "refFraction")], test, n=trials)
```

But this gives me the error `incorrect length of 'x'`

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to apply a function that compares two values in each row of a data frame (that has other members)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this via mapply, using your same function

```
 test <- function(x, p, n){binom.test(x, n, p, alternative="two-sided")}

 mapply(test, data$readcount, data$refFraction, MoreArgs=list(n=trials))
```

This will pass, element wise, data$readcount to x, data$refFraction to y, and then trials to n.  By elementwise, I mean that mapply will iterate over 1:nrow(data), and then pass the first element of data$readcount and the first element of data$refFraction to test, then subsequently the second element of both, third element, fourth, ect.

Logically this makes a lot of sense to me as mapping well to what you're trying to do and also gives you a nice way to access the information as output is a data frame where rows are the different outputs of the test function.

```
 #output

#                 [,1]                   [,2]                     [,3]                   [,4]                      
#statistic   8                      2                        7                      1                         
#parameter   15                     15                       15                     15                        
#p.value     0.44074232315963679518 0.0001140445360346263213 0.60881612435467258315 0.000019338859687764081761
#conf.int    Numeric,2              Numeric,2                Numeric,2              Numeric,2                 
#estimate    0.53333333333333332593 0.13333333333333333148   0.46666666666666667407 0.066666666666666665741   
#null.value  0.42563646589405834675 0.62898111436516046524   0.54625841975212097168 0.60785512323491275311    
#alternative "two.sided"            "two.sided"              "two.sided"            "two.sided"               
#method      "Exact binomial test"  "Exact binomial test"    "Exact binomial test"  "Exact binomial test"     
#data.name   "x and n"              "x and n"                "x and n"              "x and n"
```

As a note while it looks like confidence intervals are not coming through in this method, trying to grab one gives the following

```
# [[1]]
# [1] 0.26586134727739663131 0.78733327048069212672
# attr(,"conf.level")
# [1] 0.94999999999999995559
```

So they are preserved, just not visually outputted

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work. If it doesn't, do a `dput(head(data))` and reply here.

```
test = function(x,...) {binom.test(x = x["readCount"], p = x["refFraction"], ...)}
result = apply(X = data[,c("readCount", "refFraction")], MARGIN = 1, FUN = test, n = trials)
```

Generate some fake data to test

```
trials = 15
data = data.frame(readCount = sample(1:10, rep=T), refFraction = runif(10))
> head(result, 2)

[[1]]

    Exact binomial test

data:  x["readCount"] and trials
number of successes = 10, number of trials = 15, p-value = 0.2008
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.4877061
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3838037 0.8817589
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.6666667 


[[2]]

    Exact binomial test

data:  x["readCount"] and trials
number of successes = 4, number of trials = 15, p-value = 0.4325
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.386819
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.07787155 0.55100324
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.2666667
```